# vscode slowly loosing features

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

when I started using VSCode I got really nice auto completes and when I hovered over variables or methods I would get a pop-up that would show me what's in the variable or what arguments that method takes, now <tag>'s don't auto close and attributes don't auto add ="" nothing shows up when I hover over things.

I have completely uninstalled and reset VSCode, in every way I have found on the internet, I tried copying my GitHub code space settings(which was working as expected) but there were no extensions installed on the code space and nothing but a theme in the settings so I didn't have anything to copy over to my desktop, but I accidentally synced the settings of my desktop version to the code space now the code space has the same problems my desktop version had, even though there are no settings in the settings.json folder on my desktop, also no extensions installed.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to your %appdata% folder on windows and delete the Code, then uninstall vscode and reinstall it. just uninstalling it doesnt get rid of that Code folder.